# Can I call a recorded audio as "Recording"?

Tags: word-choice

The way I see things - 'Recording' is a process, and a 'Record' is a result of the recording. But I heard some people call an audio file that was just recorded 'Recording'.

- Is calling a recorded audio 'Recording' correct?
- Am I correct assuming that it's better to call the recorded file as a 'Record' rather than 'Recording'?

Comment: I would actually call recorded audio **a** recording. Mind the moved article :) _**A record**_ brings to mind an actual old-fashioned disc, so I would not use that unless that is what I actually mean.

Comment: @oerkelens Record seems right to me. A record does bring to mind the musical disc, yes, but I think of a record in a data sense as well. I do computer work, so I guess that might be a part of it, but I also think of dental records and things like that, where a record is simply evidence of an occurrence kept in some "permanent" form. So to keep a file named "Record" seems logical... though I can't answer the question itself.

Comment: @Ice-9: yes, _record_ has many meanings and uses, but when referring to **audio** I do not associate "record" with a recorded piece of audio that does not reside on a vinyl disc. (Except when it is used instead of "album": "the band's new record is out now." - That is usually a CD.)

Comment: This question as written, is off-topic as a general reference.  (I was able to answer it with a dictionary link to the word in question.)  If you want to ask a much more interesting and on-topic question, ask *Why is this form acceptable as a noun?*  It will probably yield a more interesting answer and not get closed as gen-ref.  (It may be closed as too broad or POB, but definitely not gen-ref.)

Comment: @oerkelens Ah, okay. I see. I didn't make the connection at all with "referring to audio" so I just completely misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not uncommon to use verb-ing as a noun to indicate the *result* of doing something.

In the case of recording, there is the word *record* as well, but it is usually a reference to a (vinyl) disc to be played on a record-player.

The result of writing something can simply be called writing as well (although *writ* exists as well - mostly archaic):

> Read the writing on the wall.

Another example is the filling of a pie. I can refer to the action of filling the pie, but once I serve it, I can tell you the pie has a home-made filling. (Your teeth can have fillings too, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

[Recording is an accepted noun for the product of the process of recording.](http://m.dictionary.com/definition/recording)

Compare this to a similar form in the word shaving.

> His hot chocolate was topped with whipped cream and chocolate shavings.

It is a noun that describes the product of the verb process of shaving.

Comment: And those shavings even form a _topping_, the result of the process of topping the hot chocolate with the shavings :)

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, great to see some references to respected sources.

Comment: @DoctororDrive Dictionary.com is my go to for the soul reason that it is free.  I much prefer OED, but I don't wish to pay $295 a year to prove my pedantic linguistic points.  I have a dusty paper copy that was bought and paid for years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Recording in this context is a gerund, that is a verbal noun. It is possible to make most verbs into a noun by adding -ing.

I liked her singing. Smoking is bad for your health. A record has become known as a tangible object made from vinyl, or something recorded in a retrievable form. A recording is a noun.

Comment: It's not quite the gerund either. Recording is the act of making a record. That is a verbal noun to be certain (it describes the act in noun form).  But, I'm not sure that the by-product of recording is also a gerund.